# Can we have one model serializer for multiple models having the same fields? Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have 5 models with same fields inheriting from a base model. Now for all the five models I am having 5 serializers serializing all the fields for their respective models. An example of the setup is as below

**base model**

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):

  field 1
  field 2
```

** model 1**

```
class Model1(BaseModel):
   field 3 = models.Charfield(choices=CHOICES)
```

**model 2**

```
class Model 2(BaseModel)
 field 3 = models.Charfield(choices=CHOICES)
```

So field3 is common in both the models but have different choices in them hence are placed in different models and not in the base model.

**serializer**

```
class SerialModel1(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = "__all__"
```

```
class SerialModel2(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model2
        fields = "__all__"
```

So as shown even when the models have the same fields I need to use to different model serializers.

#### Question

Can I have just one model serializer for both Model1 and Model2 ? If yes, please suggest me the way to do it.

Comment: instead of ModelSerializer try serializers.Serializer. then you can use the same serializer for both models..?

Comment: If they are linked well with foreign key it will be much easier can be done with single class

Comment: @nava no they are completely seperate models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can create a generic BaseModelSerializer [drf-doc] for this:
class BaseModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
and then use this as base class for the serializers of the concrete models:
class SerialModel1(BaseModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model1
class SerialModel2(BaseModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model2
This will inherit the fields specification, and override the model, so effectively configuring a serializer for the respective model, but reusing the field specification.
You can of course extend the BaseModelSerializer with extra fields, or override fields if necessary.
Note that normally a ModelSerializer is in fact already a "generic" serializer, in the sense that it can serialize any model you specify in the Meta class. So in a way, using a BaseModelSerializer is "overengineering" a bit, but it can prevent repeating code.
```